# volumes in docker-maven-plugin not binding

Tags: maven, docker, docker-volume, fabric8, docker-maven-plugin

I am using docker-maven-plugin to run an image from a remote repository.

The image is running using docker:start but it seems like the volumes not working.

I run the command using groovy (jenkins):

```
sh(script:"mvn -B -gs ${cfg} -f lib/pom.xml docker:start", returnStatus: true)
```

my pom.xml code is:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
  <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>

  <version>0.31.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <images>
      <image>
        <name>imageName:latest</name>
        <run>
          <volumes>
            <bind>
              <volume>/inputs:/inputs</volume>
              <volume>/out:/out</volume>
              <volume>/env:/env</volume>
            </bind>
          </volumes>
        </run>
      </image>
    </images>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: i would ask at it https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin/issues

Comment: Have you tried running the command without groovy?